# iOS - Auto Layout issue with constraints priority and compression resistance

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I have been working on improving myself concerning `Auto Layout` and creating design.

I have read a lot about *constraints priority*, *compression resistance* and *hugging priority* but also *intrinsic content size*.

After re-creating almost all xib/storyboard files in my project, I have been struggling with a simple design of a custom `UICollectionViewCell`.

Here is the required design :

[image]

But I can't seem to create appropriate constraints in order to handle all screen resolution (specifically iPhone 5).

Here is what I have done :

I have create 2 separated views, title view at the top, and contentView.

[image]

**Concerning the Blue and Gray Views :**

Now in order to always have approximately same look on different screen device, I added a constraint `equal height` between the `blue view` and the *contentView* (`white view`), with constant `1:3`. Which means the blue view will always be 1/3 of the parent white view.

And for the `gray view`, I have added an `equalHeight` constraint with the `blue view` equal to `1:2`.

**The UILabel and the 2 UIImage Views:**

Now the fun part begin, I have setup `trailing`, `top` and `bottom` constraint for the `UILabel` in the blue view, and same but `leading` for the big ImageView which is outside, with `horizontal constraints` between the `UILabel` and the alert icon `Image View`, and `horizontal constraint` between the `2 Images Views`.

Now I know I have auto layout constraint ambiguity because it doesn't know which element to compress or to clip.

EDIT : So I changed the content hugging priority of the UILabel to 1000 and now I have all my 3 elements but on an iPhone 5 the result is a catastrophe.

EDIT : Here is a global image with all the constraints. It doesn't look good on iPhone 5.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: always include the code, not just your assumptions about the code.. only the code describes the situation 100% correctly

Comment: I have added an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a constraint ambiguity because you have to set width/height constraints for the alertImageView and warningImageView, beside set contentHugging priority horizontal of the label to 1000

Also it's possible to create H spacing between the alertView and the warningView despite not being on the same container.

Comment: I didn't have set any width or height constraints neither on the imageView or the warningImageView. Just top, bottom, leading and trailing.
The contentHugging priority to 1000 did the trick, let me check on small screen.

Comment: from your design I conclude you have to set aspect ratio 1 to the alertView with height equal to 1/2 contentView , warningImageV set it's height 1/2 from blueView and also aspectRatio 1 , try and see

Comment: Why should I set aspect ratio ? When I do it, everything go red with errors.

Comment: you don't have to if you're setting top , bottom ,leading , constraints but you should give the alert imageView a width

Comment: I can't keep the same aspect ratio/size on small screen for the white and blue view. The white view is 1/2 height of the blue view, but they aren't centered on the content view. They are almost at the bottom